# Hibernate query and Session cache confusion

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in a bulk DB export application. After reading of many questions/answers and articles about Session cache i still do not understand following:

assuming entity list is loaded per HQL to iterate over it and to read values of referenced objects/collections. Will be in this case referenced objects/collections saved in Session Cache?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

When you execute a HQL query all returned Entities must be loaded in the current Session. This is because the Entities are in the ATTACHED state, so any modification can be detected by the "dirty-checking mechanism".

If you are inserting a large number of entities, it's better to [flush() and clear()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) after each batch, so that you remove the current entries from the current 1st level, since you won't need them in the next batch anyway.

If you are retrieving a large entity collection that fits your current RAM and you want the entities to be attached for the whole time you operate on a given entity, then at the end of the batch you will flush, and evict() the current processed entities. This time you don't clear() since you still want to keep the unprocessed entities attached, so that Hibernate can propagate the changes to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in every article about Hibernate cache there is a talk of NOT CACHED query results, unless second level cache is activated?

Comment: That is a great comment of yours. There are three types of caches: 1st level (Session oriented), 2nd Level (shared by all sessions), query cache (storing entity ids returned by a query, since the actual entities should be in the 2nd level cache anyway). So the query results are not cached after the transaction is ended and the session is closed, unless you activate the 2nd level cache and the query cache.

Comment: Please take a look at following article: http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-one-the-session-cache/ , especially following sentence: "Using the code above we would expect the query to be executed only once. However if we look at the PurePath of this transaction we can see, that two database queries have been executed."

Comment: The session cache kicks in when using session.find() or session.load() as opposed to when executing a query by id. Hibernate doesn't translate such queries to get()/load(), but simply creates the query and executes it. If the result is already cached, it will return the previous cached entry, so even if 2 queries are executed you will still get the same object reference as long as you executed them in the same Session.